# Wordpress asynchronous publish button

Tags: wordpress, asynchronous, publish

:)

We are currently having issues with long loading times in admin-mode when there are 40+ editors hacking away in our WP backend with 4000+ pages. Since we cannot use the cache here, we need another approach.

I wonder if it is possible to make the whole 'Publish'/'Update' being asynchronous instead of making a post?

I've started to look into this:
https://github.com/techcrunch/wp-async-task

However, I don't know how to implement the correct behavior.
Have this been done before?

BR / Henric